# My Samsung S4 won't connect to my computer

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-kies, mtp

I have downloaded *Samsung Kies 3,* and the computer wont even find the device. I have tried different USB ports and nothing seems to work. I have tried changing it to a media device manually but I cant find the right spot. What else can I do to get the device recognized?

Comment: When you connect does your phone start to charge?

Comment: Does it charge? Do you have the right version of Kies for your Firmware version? Can you access the phone through windows explorer and see your files? Have you tried Kies Lite or Kies Air also? Are you running custom firmware or is your device status 'custom', if so Kies won't recognise it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your Device drivers wasn't successfully installed in your pc

Here is couple of things you can do,:

- Uninstall Kies
- Go to device manager of your pc and remove/uninstall anything related to samsung
- Reboot your device(optional)
- Then Download Kies to your computer and while installing dont connect your s4 with pc.
- After installation connect your Device and let it install device driver sucessfully.

Hope this will Help you, For more information See this

[S4 connect issue](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/282817-pc-cant-detect-galaxy-s4.html)

[Link 2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2500213)